# Google Chrome Update Caused Issues on CanvasJS

Tags: charts, chromium, axis-labels, canvasjs, gridlines

After Google Chrome’s latest update, I face incorrect behavior for charts. Mostly mouse events (e.g. zooming, panning) make axis lines, grid lines and axis labels disappear periodically. Does anyone faced this kind of issue?

Nothing has been done from my side in form of code changes or even commits. Just after Chrome update, canvasJS behaves paranormally.

Comment: [CanvasJS Charts](https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/) (v3.7.27GA) seems to be working properly across all the browsers Chrome (v119.0.6045.160), Firefox (v119.0.1), Edge (v119.0.2151.72), Opera (v104.0.4944.72), Safari (v16.1).